# Convert BigInteger to ULong in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, biginteger

Given a `BigInteger` in Kotlin that is in the range between 0 and 2^64, how can I convert this `BigInteger` to a `ULong`? Kotlin provides `toULong()` extension methods [only for Byte/Short/Int/Long/Float/Double](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-u-long.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely do `bigint.toLong().toULong()`.

The `toLong()` extension calls `BigInteger.longValue()`. The documentation for that says "if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned".

Then the `Long.toULong()` extension is documented as "The resulting ULong value has the same binary representation as this Long value."

So with those two together, we can see that `toLong().toULong()` will preserve all 64 bits of a BigInteger between 0 and 2^64-1.